# How to input <bean:message> into <display:column>

Tags: displaytag

I have a message like this

```
appSearch.urlApplicationInfo=http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/snquery.pl?APPL_ID={0}
```

Then I want to read and put it in the Application Number column. So, when user clicks on  a record, he/she will be navigated to other page.

```
<display:table id="row">
    <display:column title="Application Number" sortable="true" style="width=20%">
        <html:link href="<bean:message key='appSearch.urlApplicationInfo' arg0='${row.applicationNumber}' />"> ${row.applicationNumber}</html:link>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

My method didn't work, it didn't read the message and put in the `href` attribute.
I'm looking forward to hearing from you. I do appreciate for all your contributions!


**FIXED:**

Use `<a href>` instead:

```
<a href="<bean:message key='appSearch.urlApplicationInfo' arg0='${row.applicationNumber}'/>">${row.applicationNumber}</a>
```

Thanks anyway!!!